# How to stop ngrx-forms reinitializing actions?

Tags: angular, forms, ngrx, angular-forms

[this question is based on https://ngrx-forms.readthedocs.io/]

I've an array of topics(strings) inside my angular component. I'm using ngrx-store to manage state along with ngrx-forms for managing forms.
During the initialization of the component, I dispatch some actions for each topic inside the component.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formState$ = this.store.pipe(select(s => s.filterByTopics.formState))
    this.topicsOptions$ = this.store.pipe(select(s => s.filterByTopics.topicsOptions))
    Object.keys(this.topics).forEach(topic => this.store.dispatch(new CreateTopicControlAction(topic)))
  }
```

That works fine and the ngrx-form controls are getting added.

But the real issue is that if I again visit the same component again it reinitializes the actions (since ngOnInit contains all the actions) and spits out an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Group 'filterByTopicsForm.topics' already has child control '0'!
```

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5u7S.png)

How can I prevent this?

Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of [ngrx-forms](https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms) here.

This is not an issue with **ngrx-forms** per se, but more a general question of how to prevent double initialization when state is in the store, and therefore not coupled to a component's lifetime.

I see multiple options here:

1. reset the form in `ngOnDestroy` by dispatching a `SetValueAction` with an initial value as well as a `ResetAction` (or create your own custom action to recreate the form state in the reducer); this emulates the behaviour of @angular/forms where a form lives only as long as the owning component; here's how that could look like with a custom action with ngrx v8+:

   ```js
   const resetMyForm = createAction('MY_FORM/reset');

   const myFormReducer = createReducer(
     {
       formState: createFormGroupState('MY_FORM', INITIAL_FORM_VALUE),
     },
     onNgrxForms(),
     on(resetMyForm, ({ formState }, { lang, code }) => ({
       formState: createFormGroupState('MY_FORM', INITIAL_FORM_VALUE),
     })),
   );
   ```
2. Check if the form is already initialized in the component

   ```js
   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.formState$ = this.store.pipe(select(s => s.filterByTopics.formState))
     this.topicsOptions$ = this.store.pipe(select(s => s.filterByTopics.topicsOptions))
     Object.keys(this.topics).forEach(topic => {
       this.formState$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(formState => {
         // how exactly this `if` looks like depends on your concrete form state shape
         if (!formState.controls.topics.controls[topic]) {
           this.store.dispatch(new CreateTopicControlAction(topic))
         }
       })
     })
   }
   ```
3. Check if the form is already initialized in the reducer

   ```js
   const createTopicControl = createAction('MY_FORM/createTopicControl', (topic: string) => ({ topic }));

   const myFormReducer = createReducer(
     {
       formState: createFormGroupState('MY_FORM', INITIAL_FORM_VALUE),
     },
     onNgrxForms(),
     on(createTopicControl, (state, { topic }) => {
       if (state.formState.controls.topics.controls[topic]) {
         return state
       }

       // add form control ...
     }),
   );
   ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've two other questions. Can you please answer that too?